# Is it possible to get Facebook posts by #hashtag in Graph API 2.3?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm creating a web page which pulls all posts for certain hashtag from Twitter, Instagram, and Facebook.

I'm trying to get facebook posts by hashtag and show those posts in my web page, and trying to use graph API javascript SDK for it. Twitter and instagram was easier... but facebook is actually giving me some challenge.

I see there's a documentation here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/hashtag

Javascript SDK says

```
FB.api(
"/{hashtag-id}",
function (response) {
  if (response && !response.error) {
    /* handle the result */
  }
}
);
```

What's supposed to go into "/{hashtag-id}"?

I've tried putting in the real hashtag (something like %23fail) instead of {hashtag-id} but it seems to give this error:
"(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: #fail"

I've also played around with the Graph API explorer, but I can't seem to be able to pull any posts by the hashtag.

It seems to be working on the facebook website.
https://www.facebook.com/hashtag/fail

is that possible for developers to do using Graph API?

Thanks.

Comment: No it is not available in the API

Comment: @WizKid It does appear to be part of the API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/hashtag